# I'm having trouble figuring out how to automate OAuth authentication to access Google Drive. (Python)

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, oauth, google-drive-api

#### What we want to solve

1. access the shared drive with a user account by OAuth authentication
2. retrieve spreadsheet -> convert to parquet type 3. save to GCS
3. save to GCS

These processes are written in the main() function below, and I would like to apply them to periodic processing every day using CloudFunction and CloudScheduler.

However, as it is, the code below requires the user to manually log in to his/her Google account by going to the browser.
I would like to rewrite the code so that this login can be done automatically, but I am having trouble understanding it...
I would appreciate it if someone could help me...

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)

```py
 ### ※※Authentication is required by browser※※
creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
```

```py
### Result
Please visit this URL to authorize this application: 
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=132987612861-
4j24afrouontpeiv5ryy7sn64inhr.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=
http%yyy%2Flocalhost%3yy6%2F&scope=httpsyyF%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive.
readonly&state=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&access_type=offline
```

The readonly&state=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX part changes with each execution.

Browser screen that transitions when the above code section is executed

#### The entire relevant source code

```py
from __future__ import print_function
import io
import os
import key
import json
import os.path
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
from pprint import pprint
from webbrowser import Konqueror
from google.cloud import storage as gcs
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.http import MediaIoBaseDownload, MediaIoBaseUpload, MediaFileUpload
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly']

def main(event, context):
    """Drive v3 API
    Function to access shared Drive→get Spreadsheet→convert to parquet→upload to GCS    """
    creds = None
    file_id = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' #Unedited data in shared drive
    mime_type = 'text/csv'

    # OAuth authentication to access shared drives
    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
     # Allow users to log in if there are no (valid) credentials available    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            ### ※※Browser authentication required※※
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)##Currently, we need a manual login here!
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())
    try:
        # Retrieve spreadsheets from shared drives
        service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
        request = service.files().export_media(fileId=file_id, mimeType=mime_type)
        fh = io.BytesIO()
        downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)
        done = False
        print(io.StringIO(fh.getvalue().decode()))

        while done is False:
            status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
        # Read "Shared Drive/SpreadSheet" -> convert to parquet
        df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(fh.getvalue().decode()))
        table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df)
        buf = pa.BufferOutputStream()
        pq.write_table(table, buf,compression=None)

        # service_account for save to GCS
        key_path = 'service_account_file.json'
        service_account_info = json.load(open(key_path))
        credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(service_account_info)
        client = gcs.Client(
            credentials=credentials,
            project=credentials.project_id,
        )

        # GCS information to be saved 
        bucket_name = 'bucket-name'
        blob_name = 'sample-folder/daily-data.parquet'#save_path
        bucket = client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
        blob = bucket.blob(blob_name)

        # parquet save to GCS
        blob.upload_from_string(data=buf.getvalue().to_pybytes())
        # ↓If a print appears, the data has been saved.
        print("Blob '{}' created to '{}'!".format(blob_name, bucket_name))

    except HttpError as error:
        # TODO(developer) - Handle errors from drive API.
        print(f'An error occurred: {error}')
```

#### What I tried by myself

I tried to use selenium to run the browser, but could not implement it well because the browser login URL is different each time. ←I may be able to find a way to do it.

Comment: I think (!?) that the only way you can automate Google Workspace apps **without** direct user involvement is by using [Google Workspace Domain-wide Delegation of Authority](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation). Otherwise (direct) user interaction (in the auth flow) is a security requirement by Google to prevent access to user data.

Comment: How about this flow - 1) User goes to a UI and authorizes your App 2) A token is generated when user authorizes your App and you store this token 3) Going forward, your App executes requests using this stored token on behalf of a user. The problem though is that if your App is in 'test status', that token will expire every 14 days and user has to reauthorize your App. However, if your App is in Production status, then the token can be stored indefinitely

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://medium.com/weareservian/automate-data-ingestion-from-google-drive-to-google-cloud-storage-879d8ad6def) approach. Worked for me!

The solution consists in create a service account and share your data folder with the SA e-mail.

[Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/manage-sharing)
[Service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts?hl=pt_br)

Comment: This way I will be able to accomplish my task!
Thank you!

However, it may be difficult to access the service account since this time the access is to a highly secure shared drive.
If there is a way to authenticate with a user account like I was trying, that would be preferred.

If it is difficult, I will try the method you have taught me.
Please let me know if anyone can help. Thanks.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).